# MySQL vs binary files speed

Tags: c++, mysql, c, binaryfiles

Which is better way  to save data in c++ ?
**Binary File(.dat) or Mysql** .
Wil binary files perform faster execution or Mysql?

Comment: These are completely different and non comparable concepts!

Comment: Try to rename your file into "foo.dat" and see if the execution time is any faster by naming it that way. My suspicion is the answer is no but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 4):

MySQL (and most other database management systems for that matter) actually [stores its data in binary files](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/frm-file-format.html). This is common because reading and writing from a binary file (as opposed to plain text) can be very fast, if the contents of the file are structured optimally.

So, technically, if you store data in MySQL, you're storing it in a binary file. However, this doesn't mean that binary files always provide faster access to data than databases.

A database management system is an [abstraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_%28computer_science%29) of the underlying data (e.g., binary file). As such, it can provide additional benefits, including (but not limited to):

- **Cache frequently accessed data** (reading from memory is much faster than reading from a binary file)
- **Support finer grained security models** (e.g., allowing certain users read data, while allowing others to modify it)
- **Simplified view of the data** (not having to worry about how the data is actually persisted)

Ultimately, MySQL and binary files just fill different roles, with some overlap.

If you just want to store application data (e.g., user preferences) for later use, then you should prefer using a binary file. A database would work, but would be overkill.

If you're storing large amounts of data, or data with internal relationships, then you should consider using a database management system (like MySQL). A binary file would work, but would be hard to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you are doing. Binary files will be fastest (mmap them for max speed) for pure read/write speed. Mysql is easier to use if you're going to do anything database-y.